# Horizontally centered on a horizontally scrolling page

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling, alignment

I'm trying to develop a horizontally scrolling website in which clicking a link in the navigation scrolls the page to the right to the linked div.

The problem is I want the elements that it scrolls to to be horizontally centered within the browser window. I assume that this can be done using javascript, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Here is a pastebin link to my HTML: http://pastebin.com/YxajLvtW
And here is the CSS: http://pastebin.com/JpaJC2Yg

I know how to implement javascript, but not necessarily read/write it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful: http://www.arvindandrion.com/jquery/horizontal-scroll-using-jquery-scrollto/

General advice: Use a Javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to code Javascript functionality. It makes life a loooooot easier :)

Maybe take a look at this, too: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: Well I already have the horizontal scrolling part, I just wanted to figure out the horizontally centered part. Scrollto and scrollleft are just to auto-scroll to the next element, right?

I've always used margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto, but that breaks when the container width is wider than the browser.

Comment: I updated it here, I'm not sure if it's working though: http://jsfiddle.net/8abWm/2/
A functioning version is here: http://ikilledtheinter.net/centered/
Obviously it's just simlpe horizontal scrolling structure right now, I'm just trying to get the elements working.

Really the only thing I'm asking is how to horizontally center (in relation to the browser) each element of the page.